# Setting a SurfaceView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

What's up guys, I have a pretty silly problem, but I really can't figure this one out. I'm trying to set a view extending SurfaceView for a fragment. Here's the hosting activity's onCreate method:

```
public class ProbeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

BattleSurfaceView BSView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BSView = new BattleSurfaceView(this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    BattleFragment fragment = new BattleFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(BSView.getId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}

And here's the fragment:

```
public class BattleFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener
{   
/* Surface View for this activity */
BattleSurfaceView BSView;
DummySpell sp;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* instantiating the surface view */
    BSView = new BattleSurfaceView(this.getActivity());
    /* setting the listener - this, because it is defined within the activity */
    BSView.setOnTouchListener(this);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.BSView;
}
    ...
```

}

Each time, I get a 'no view found' exception. What am I missing?
Thanks a lot, hope you'll work this out. Cheers

Comment: In which line does the exception pop up?

Comment: 11-12 21:44:59.598: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.doomsdaybunnies.siikonkurs/pl.doomsdaybunnies.siikonkurs.ui.ProbeMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0xffffffff for fragment BattleFragment{40d83278 #0 id=0xffffffff}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to show your custom SurfaceView ('MySurfaceView') in the fragment, then just do the following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new BattleSurfaceView(getActivity());
    }
```